# Как грамотно обработать деление на ноль?

Tags: c#, исключения

Есть унаследованный класс:

```
public class Division : BinaryOperation
{
    protected override decimal Calculate(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        return a / b;
    }

    public override string Name { get { return "Деление"; } }
}
```

Как внутри него красиво и логично обработать ситуацию деления на ноль? Если обернуть в try-catch, что писать в catch? Допустим, я не знаю какие контролы будут на форме, и вообще, будет ли это использоваться в WinForms или WPF или что-то еще, чтобы куда то выводить текст Exception'а. Возможно есть еще какие-то хорошие варианты кроме try-catch?

Comment: внутри него лучше никак не обрабатывать

Comment: вы не должны его обрабатывать, это задача вызывающего кода, равно как проверка передаваемых в операцию параметров перед вызовом.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Сложность в "элегантной" обработке исключений заключается в том, что она сильно зависит от контекста.

Вот, например, в одном приложении, нужно выделить UI контрол и попросить пользователя ввести валидное значение. В другом приложении (если оно серверное), нужно бросить исключение, которое должно пересечь границы приложения тем или иным способом. А в третьем приложении, проверка аргументов происхоидт на более высоком уровне и передача 0 в параметр `b` является багом и должно привести к крэшу приложения.

Все это приводит к следующим возможностям:

1. Добавить предусловие в метод `Calculate`, что `b != 0`: `Contract.Requires(b != 0)`. В этом случае мы переклаыдваем ответственность за валидацию кода на вызывающую сторону. Мы говорим, что 0 - это невалидное значение, и просим клиента нас не трогать в этом случае.
2. Ничего не делать и пробрасывать `DivideByZeroException`. Еще одна альтернатива: задокументировать метод `Calculate` и "сказать", что из него может прилететь это исключение.

В этом случае мы опять же перекладываем ответственность на вызывающий код, который лучше знает, что с ним делать. Теперь клиент может выдать сообщение, отправить нужный ответ клиенту или преобразовать это исключение в какое-то другое.

3. Добавить новый уровень косвенности. Еще, можно добавить специальный тип исключения, например, `CalculationException` или `OperationException`. В этом случае, новый тип исключения будет описывать семейство ошибок, которое может произойти при работе с абстрактной операцией.

Это решение является более расширяемым, поскольку новые наследники могут бросать новые и новые типы исключений, а конкретный тип исключения может содержать более специфичную информацию:

```
public abstract class OperationException { }

public class DivideByZeroOperationException : OperationException {}

public class Division : BinaryOperation
{
    protected override decimal Calculate(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        if (b == 0) {throw new DivideByZeroOperationException();}

        return a / b;
    }
}
```

Теперь клиент может решить, нужно ли ему обрабатывать базовое исключение или же более специфичное.

4. Еще одна альтернатива, вернуться к умным кодам возврата и уйти от исклчюений.

Пример:

```
public enum Error { DivideByZero, YetAnotherError }

// Это такой себе 'Either' тип, который может содержать либо ошибку (код и,
// возможно, сообщение), либо валидный результат
public class OperationResult {
  public decimal? Result {get;}
  public Error? Error {get;}

  public static OperationResult Success(decimal result) {
  }

  public static OperationResult Failure(Error error) {
  // Может быть стоит добавить сообщение или другую контекстную инфомрацию
  }
}

public class Division : BinaryOperation
{
    protected override OperationResult Calculate(decimal a, decimal b)
    {
        if (b == 0) {return OperationResult.Error(Error.DivideByZero);}
        return a / b;
    }

}
```

Это более "функциональный" подход, в то время, как предыдущие являются более каноническими в ОО языках, таких как C#.

Главное заключение: **не существует вменяемого способа полностью обработать исключение внутри метода `Calculate`**. Информация об ошибке должна быть передана вызывающему коду, поскольку только на более высоком уровне существует достаточно инфомрации (контекста), чтобы обработать эту проблему полноценным образом.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, это какой-то вычислитель общего вида. В этом вычислителе должна быть общая система ошибок, которую и должен использовать этот конкретный класс операции деления.

Использование исключений скорее всего недопустимо по многим причинам. В частности, деление на ноль в данной области это во-первых нормальная ситуация, а во-вторых не означает что надо уничтожить что-нибудь по случаю "ошибки" и убрать кого-то со стека.

Скорее всего, общая система обработки ошибок вычислений должна предусматривать явно ошибку или даже список (иерархический) ошибок как возможный результат любой операции. Вариантов дизайна такой схемы куча - можно начать с подсказок из ответа Sergey Teplyakov.

И ещё не забудьте, что в вычислителях общего вида деление на ноль не всегда ошибка, а иногда infinity да ещё и positive или negative, или даже NaN!